# Getting "Invalid call" when using require with Typescript and Expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, require, expo

I am trying to play some audio in a react-native app created with the expo-cli.

The code is written in typescript and the offending code looks like this, taken from the [expo.io documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/):

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { WorkoutComponent } from "./WorkoutExecutor";
import { Audio } from 'expo';

export default class AudioPlayer {

    private async playAudio(fileName: string) {
        console.log("Playing Audio: " + fileName);
        const soundFile = './assets/sounds/' + fileName + '.mp3';
        try {
            const { sound: soundObject, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
              require(soundFile),
              { shouldPlay: true }
            );
            // Your sound is playing!
          } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            // An error occurred!
          }
          
    }
[...]
}
```

When the app loads, it gives the following error, even before it gets to the screen with the sound

```
[...]\src\AudioPlayer.ts:Invalid call at line 13: require(soundFile)
```

I realize that the code example is with javascript and not typescript, but what am I missing?

My tsconfig.json is the one from the expo typescript example and looks like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    // Using the type definitions in @types/expo because they are still better than the ones provided by expo. See SvgScreen.tsx and SystemFontsScreen.tsx.
    "paths": {
      "expo": [
        "../node_modules/@types/expo",
        "../node_modules/expo"
      ],
    },
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got help via Twitter, and the problem is that `require()` does not work with dynamic values. This also explains why the errors happened before the app was even loaded, as it tried to resolve the `require` at build or load time and not at runtime as I had thought.

Comment: That explains the error. And do you have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { WorkoutComponent } from "./WorkoutExecutor";
import { Audio } from 'expo';

const fileA = require('path/to/sound/file.mp3');
const fileB = require('path/to/sound/file2.mp3');

export default class AudioPlayer {

    private async playAudio(fileName: string) {
       if (fileName == 'A') {
           var soundFile = fileA;
       } else {
           var soundFile = fileB;
       }
       try {
          const { sound: soundObject, status } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
          soundFile,
          { shouldPlay: true }
        );
        // Your sound is playing!
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        // An error occurred!
      }

}
[...]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it by using

```
import song from "./path_to_song/song.mp3"
```

Comment: But that only works on static values known when the app starts. My problem was that I was trying to load a file that I didn't know the filename of on app load. I ended up using a different method for loading the file.

Comment: > I ended up using a different method for loading the file.

What method? https://xkcd.com/979/