# React Native using list of image in state with for loop

Tags: image, react-native, for-loop, state

I'm beginner in react native. I want to use list of image and then push them to the child page with for loop

here is my code to explain what am I say.

```
    state ={
    a: ['./assest/image1.jpg','./assest/image2.jpg','./assest/image3.jpg'],
  }

  b = () => {
    let d = [];
    for (var i = 0; i<=this.state.a.lenght - 1; i++){
    if (this.state.a[i] == ' ') { }
    else {
    d.push(<Child images={this.state.a[i]} />)
      }
    }
    return d;
    };
 
    render() {
    return <ScrollView style={styles.body}>

      {this.b()}
    </ScrollView>
    }
    }
```

And this is the code of child page which gives image url and set it to  with props

```
    constructor(props)
{
super(props);
}

  render()
  {
  
  return <View style ={ styles.body}>


<Image style={styles.image}>{this.props.images}</Image>
  </View>
    }
  }
```

What is the correct way to use list of image urls in state

And how to push them with for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
    a: ['./assest/image1.jpg','./assest/image2.jpg','./assest/image3.jpg'],
  }

render() {
    return (
       <ScrollView style={styles.body}>
       {
          this.state.a.map((url,key) => 
             <View style ={ styles.body}>
                 <Image 
                    style={styles.image} 
                    source={require(url)} // <--- changed
                  />
             </View>
          )
       }
       </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Comment: What should I write in {key}?

Comment: Nothing. just copy-paste the code and it would work. Whenever you have time I would really recommand you to read about the js 'map' and 'forEach' functions as they will become part of the basic of your development.

Comment: Thanks,Did you write correct Curly brackets and Round brackets,there is a error after />

Comment: I added ')' after the '/>'. It should be fine now.

Comment: I have been Engaged with two error first this one Error: The <Image> component cannot contain
children. if you want to render content on top of the image , consider using the <ImageBackground>
component or absolute positioning. and after I changed Image to Imagebackground then encountered with another,error: the  text string must be rendered whitin a <text> component.

Comment: That is another problem. Your child component has Image tag with children which is not allowed. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Error:TransformError Components\Child.js: Components\Child.js:Invalid call at line 46: require(this.props.images),Should I use for loop to fetch urls from props,I think we have forgotten to push key to child, Should I use this.props.key ?

Comment: Nope. There's a missing curly bracket at the Image tag line (see source prop). That might be the problem.

Comment: No,I've written correctly, If it was curly brackets error,the visual studio code told me syntax error not invalid call.

Comment: I edited the answer so the child is nested inside the parent as I suspect the problem is related to the image path as the image path is relative and not a uri. Try this and make sure the path is correct (in the case above the this js file sits at the same place as the 'assets' folder. Just note the styles should be changed accordingly.

Comment: See the changed row

Comment: Again invalid call error, please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581073/getting-invalid-call-when-using-require-with-typescript-and-expo

Comment: That makes sense. When using require you are using relative path so there is no much logic in retrieving it dynamically. I always use "uri" so never had this problem.